# EF4: OfType filter for GetObjectStateEntries

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4

I override the SaveChanges method in my datacontext and have the following code:

```
IEnumerable<BaseEntity> newEntries = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added).OfType<BaseEntity>();
```

In my model all businessobjects derive from BaseEntity. When I add a new 'Investment' (also derived from BaseEntity!) to my datacontext the code above will not show this entity in the resultset.

`GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)` however returns one entity which is of type `Investment`.

Why doesn't `OfType<>` recognize if an object is derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because this query returns objects of type `ObjectStateEntry` and instance of this object has a property `Entity` which holds your entity object.

Try this:

```
var IEnumerable<BaseEntity> newEntries = ObjectStateManager
    .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
    .Select(e => e.Entity)
    .OfType<BaseEntity>();
```

Comment: So how would I get all added entities that are derived from BaseEntity?